# clay strips brush not working

Tags: sculpting

the clay strips brush is not working like it should.It is very smooth and I dont have autosmooth on as well . [image: this is the clay strips brush I've used on a uv sphere at subdivisions level 5]Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem at first, but then got desired behavior after choosing the following settings:

- Clay Strips brush
- Dyntopo: On

Then, in the Dyntopo settings:

- Refine Method: Subdivide Edges
- Detailing: Brush Detail
- Smoothing Shading: On

I cranked the brush strength to 1.0, and left Autosmooth off.

This was tested in Blender 2.83, 2.90 and 2.92 and seems to get the expected results.

[image]